# Why am I getting "Use of uninitialized value in hash element"?

Tags: perl

```
..
use strict;
use warnings;
...

my (%customer);
%customer = ();
...
 17 sub _customer_id {
 18     my $customer_r = shift;
 19     unless(defined $customer{$customer_r}){
 20         $customer{$customer_r} = ++$customer_id;
 21     }
 22     $customer{$customer_r};
 23 }
```

I'm just checking whether some hash key exists.

But getting the `Use of uninitialized value in hash element` at line `19`,`20`,`22`.

Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This error means `$customer_r` is `undef`.

How are you calling this function?

Comment: Yes.  You are either calling the function with no arguments or with `undef` as the first argument.  Find where that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this statement.
`my $customer_r = shift;`

If `$customer_r` gets some empty value, then you would get this error when you try to use this variable.
Basically, whenever you try to use an empty variable(not initialised), you would encounter this error.